# Jinja template to calculate the average

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm trying to display the average of numbers using jinja template but I couldn't make it up.

I'm getting the value of 'points' column from the Google app engine datastore entity 'Score'

Using python code and taking it in jinja template and I wanted to calculate the average of points and display through this template.

```
{% for num in number%}
        {{num.points}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jinja is a *layout* language, don't try to do code tasks in that language. It's great doing loops and conditionals, not great for doing arithmetic.

Calculate your average in the Python code and pass that value into your template.

Comment: Thanks! already I'm rendering a dictionary to the template, self.response.write(template.render(dic)).  I did the average calculation in the python code but how to pass this value to the same template. Please advice.

Comment: @Anna Add it to the dictionary being passed in. Every key in that dictionary becomes a name in the template, so an extra `dic['average'] = calculated_average` can then be accessed in the template as `average`.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) I passed the average through the existing dictionary and the value is displayed from template :)

Comment: Nice recommendation, but it doesn't contain the answer to the actual question.

Comment: @JoséM.Fernández-Alba: yet it still is true as ever. Don't use a display template to make calculations that are far better handled in Python.

Answer (score 11):

```
{% set score = [] %}
{% for num in number %}
    {% if score.append(num) %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
Average score: 
{{ score | sum / score | count }}
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/